# Visual Studio Shared Projects Images/CSS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, .net-core, shared-project

I have a Shared Project and a .net Core 2.0 web app which references the shared project. My intention is to maintain a set of common css and images within the shared project for use by multiple web apps. But I can't work out how to include the images and css in the web app. e.g. how do they end up in the wwwroot/dist folder? A great many blogs rave about how great Shared Projects are and how they can be used for css and images but never actually explain how to use them to do so.

Comment: I have the same question, did you find an answer for this?

Comment: @Matthew Christianson: Because you can't. Sharing CSS/Images using shared projects works, but only when you publish them. When you want to develop/debug on localhost, these files are missing. Shared projects are useless for web-development (CSS/JS/HTML). If they'd make a demo instead of evangelizing, you'd realize that this doesn't suffice.